Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION 2
I'm having trouble with this code: This is the MainActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.startRecordingButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            checkAndRequestNotificationPermission();
            requestOverlayPermission();
        });
        setupActivityResultLaunchers();
        mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }


private void startScreenCaptureService(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ScreenRecordingService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("resultCode", resultCode);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("data", data);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }

This is the onCreate method:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startButton = findViewById(R.id.startRecordingButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            checkAndRequestNotificationPermission();
            requestOverlayPermission();
        });
        setupActivityResultLaunchers();
        mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }

The logcat gives me the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=942076684, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.aksdnkasndknasd/com.example.aksdnkasndknasd.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:6063)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:6102)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:313)
at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:92)
at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:83)
at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:285)
at com.example.aksdnkasndknasd.MainActivity.lambda$setupActivityResultLaunchers$2$com-example-aksdnkasndknasd-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:66)
at com.example.aksdnkasndknasd.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onActivityResult(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:371)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.kt:331)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.kt:786)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:152)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:9362)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:6056)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:6102) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:1064)
at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:192)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1375)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)

I've tried everything I could. I added this permission to the XML
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

And also this in the service tag:
<service
            android:name=".ScreenRecordingService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
            tools:ignore="ForegroundServicePermission" />

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Help would be much appreciated 
If you need more parts of the code to answer my question just comment under the post and I will add it to the comment or directly on the post.
